# React: updating state with computed property name

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Goal: Update local form state using computed property names.

Problem: The computed property name does not overwrite/update my state. Instead it makes multiple copies

What it currently does: New objects get added to my array

```
const [channelOptions, setChannelOptions] = useState([
    { eml: false },
    { push: false },
    { inapp: false }
]);
```

Handler to update state when checkbox element is selected

```
const channelSelectionChangeHandler = (e) => {
    setChannelOptions((prevState) => {
        return [...prevState, { [e.target.value]: e.target.checked }];
    });
};
```

Outcome - Multiple copies of inapp. The goal was to overwrite it

```
0:{eml: false}
1:{push: false}
2:{inapp: false}
3:{inapp: true}
4:{inapp: false}
5:{inapp: true}
```

What am I doing wrong? I think this is down to referencing.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If possible I will use an Object like `{ eml: false, push: false, inappropriate: false }` instead of an array of objects.

Then I set new state with `setChannelOptions(prev => ({...prev, [e.target.value]: e.target.checked }))`

If you DO need to use array of objects, you can do it like this.

```
setChannelOptions( prevState => prevState.map( x => x[e.target.value] !== undefined ? { e.target.value: e.target.checked } : x )
    });
```

What we do here is to `.map` through the array, check if the key exists (is defined). If the key exists, update with new value, else return the original object.